# Adjust font-weight in Chart.js doughnut chart

Tags: chart.js

I am using [chartjs](http://chartjs.org) to create a doughnut chart. I'm having a bit of trouble styling it exactly how I want it, the [docs](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/) aren't overly helpful in all the different chart options. Anyways, one thing that's especially bugging me is the inability to adjust the font weight. Now I didn't set up the whole thing, I'm just tweaking the styles a little bit, so I'm a bit unclear as to how it works. But is there any possible way to do this?

These are the current settings I have applied:

```
segmentShowStroke: false,
segmentStrokeWidth : 0,
percentageInnerCutout: 20,
animation : true,
animationSteps : 70,
animationEasing : "easeInOutCubic",
showLabels: true,
labelFontFamily: "'Lato'",
labelFontSize:16,
labelFontWeight: 300,
labelAlign:'center',
scaleFontStyle: '300'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use crossText instead of label, you can adjust the font weight by setting these options:

```
var options = {
        crossTextFontSize : [80],
        crossTextFontFamily : ["Open Sans"],
        crossTextFontStyle : ["bold"],
        crossTextFontColor : ["#FF0000"],
        crossTextRelativePosX : [2],
        crossTextRelativePosY : [2],
        crossTextPosX : [0],
        crossTextPosY : [0],
        crossTextAlign : ["center"],
        crossTextBaseline : ["middle"]
    }
```

I'm not sure why they decided to put the FontWeight under FontStyle, but it works.

Wiki: https://github.com/FVANCOP/ChartNew.js/wiki/100_040_CrossText